# Trying to convert this nested java forloop into python but I cannot figure out how. Is there a way to do an if statment like this for loop?

Tags: java, python

I need to figure out how to rewrite these forloops in python.

I've tried everything and its not working.

```
int len = s.length();
for(int i = 1; i<4 && i<len-2; i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j<i+4 && j<len-1; j++){
```

I just wanted to be able to do conditions in a python forloop.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the place for this, and also make sure you add the code what you have tried and It's pretty straightforward once you understand how python's for loop works.

Comment: `I've tried everything`: Edit your question to post what you've tried.

Comment: Also, I would strongly recommend you to try your hands on python tutorials beforehand

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to use multiple conditions in a for-loop in Python in the same way as in Java since for-loops themselves work differently in those languages.

However, you could do something like this:

```
l = len(s)
for i in range(1, 4):
    if i == l - 2:
        break
    for j in range(i + 1, i + 4):
        if j == l - 1:
            break
```

If you want multiple other conditions, just check them using a simple if-statement inside the loop which breaks the loop if they evaluate to true.
This way, the loop stops as soon as it reaches the bounds you specified or as soon as one of the if-statements evaluates to true.